# Zoom my image to fit better on the container

Tags: html, css

Can anyone tell me how I can zoom my image and get it like the image below?
[image: this]

I wouldn't mind using `px` to size it, but it would only create more problems. If anyone can help, I'd be very thankful.

This is my code:

```css
.food-container {
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 250px;
  width: 750px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 2.3rem;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.left-side {
  width: 66%;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.left-side>p {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.right-side {
  width: 34%;
  text-align: right;
}

.right-side>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="food-container">
  <div class="left-side">
    <h1>Get your first meal for free!</h1>
    <p>
      Healthy, tasty and hassle-free meals are waiting for you. Start eating well today. You can cancel or pause anytime. And the first meal is on us!
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="right-side">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1653256513370-8d0d519b9477?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1622&q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

The image gets like that, and I don't understand why. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use backgrund-image instead of image tag! then you can try background-size and background-position!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything on your code is good, you were only missing one small thing. Add `object-fit: cover`, it will adjust the image, keeping it's aspect ratio while filling your div width and height.

Note: You can use `object-position` to "move" your image around the container

```css
.food-container {
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 250px;
  width: 750px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 2.3rem;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.left-side {
  width: 66%;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.left-side>p {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.right-side {
  width: 34%;
  text-align: right;
}

.right-side>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="food-container">
  <div class="left-side">
    <h1>Get your first meal for free!</h1>
    <p>
      Healthy, tasty and hassle-free meals are waiting for you. Start eating well today. You can cancel or pause anytime. And the first meal is on us!
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="right-side">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1653256513370-8d0d519b9477?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1622&q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to add one thing : object-fit: cover, the image takes up all the available space.

```css
.food-container {
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 250px;
  width: 750px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 2.3rem;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.left-side {
  width: 66%;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.left-side>p {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.right-side {
  width: 34%;
  text-align: right;
}

.right-side>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="food-container">
  <div class="left-side">
    <h1>Get your first meal for free!</h1>
    <p>
      Healthy, tasty and hassle-free meals are waiting for you. Start eating well today. You can cancel or pause anytime. And the first meal is on us!
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="right-side">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1653256513370-8d0d519b9477?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1622&q=80" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My bad i didn't see that manjiro had already answered it